# Repeat citation for consecutive sentences

Tags: citations, computer-science, citation-style

When the next sentence in the paper or thesis shares the same citation with the previous one. Should cite one time only at the end of the 2end sentence or cite 2 times - one for each.

For example:

In the following paragraph, 2 sentences follow each other share same citation. Should I remove the 1st citation or not.

> Hybrid ... registration method. **(Mani and Arivazhagan 2013)** Combine
>   the output of intensity method or f... method will be the input of another.
>   **(Mani and Arivazhagan 2013)**

Comment: Maybe add page numbers to indicate that you cite different parts of the same work?

Comment: Another solution is to replace the first formal reference by an informal one: Mani and Arivazhagan demonstrated that ... and then put the formal reference at the end of the whole passage based on their work.

Comment: Similar to @greenb, maybe write: "Mani and Arivazhagan (2013) blah. They also blah-blah." Starting the second sentence with "they" makes it clear that you are referring to Mani and Arivazhagan. Similarly, you could write "their method", "this technique", ...

Answer (score 2):

I've heard that in fields different from mine this is referenced with **[(Ibid.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibid.)** for footnote-style citations. I am not sure about inline citations, but the [Chicago manual of style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Documentation/faq0242.html) says it is ok. If you google for "ibid references" you get more hints how to use this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend asking your subject-matter librarian. They are usually very familiar with the various citation methods used within your field and would be able to provide advice. Or, they'd know where to look for a potential answer.